# How to prove oracle properties in Fan and Li (2001) paper

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, likelihood, sparse, regularization

I am studying Fan and Li's 2001 paper "[Variable selection via nonconcave penalized Likelihood andits oracle properties](http://orfe.princeton.edu/%7Ejqfan/papers/01/penlike.pdf)" but I am having troubles understanding *Theorem 1* proof (page 1359). I follow the authors steps until equation (A.2).

$D_n(u)\leq\alpha_nL'(\beta_0)^Tu-\frac{1}{2}u^tI(\beta_0)un\alpha^2_n\{1+o_p(1)\}-\sum_{j=1}^s[n\alpha_np^{'}_{\lambda_n}(\vert\beta_0\vert)sgn(\beta_0)u_j+n\alpha^2_np^{''}_{\lambda_n}(\vert\beta_0\vert)u_j^2\{1+o(1)\}]$

Is here where I get lost. I know what the taylor expansion is (in its simplest case is, for instance $f(x) = f(a) + f(a)'(x-a) + \frac{1}{2}f(a)''(x-a)^2...$) but I dont see how is this formula applied here.

I assume that the Taylor formula is applied over the maximum likelihood function, but if so,  why does  $un\alpha^2_n\{1+o_p(1)\}$ appear in the second term of the equation? and where does the third term  come from?

I also have some problems understanding what the authors mean while saying in (in the paragraph just under this equation) that *By choosing a sufficiently large C, the second term dominates the first term uniformly in $\|u\|=C$*

I would appreciate any hint for understanding this proof itself, or any reading recommendation useful for this purpose.